# Generating random Number ATMega168, AVR STUDIO 4

Tags: assembly, random, numbers, avr

how can I generate a random number(command) in Avr Studio 4. I have an ATMEGA168.
I want to generate the random number, so the "warten"(waiting) has an non defined waiting time and is changing all time. So if it has decreased from 255 to 0 etc. I want it to generate a random number which defines if its going another time through the waiting or if it's going to ret.
Here's my code:

```
   .include "m168def.inc"  ;ATMega 168

    rjmp main                

main:  
    ldi r16, 0b00000100     


    out ddrB, r16           

loop:    
    ldi r16, 0b00000100    
    out portB, r16             

    rcall warten            

    ldi r16, 0b00000000     
    out portB, r16          
    rcall warten

    rjmp loop

warten:
    ldi r17,2              
w3:                         
    ldi r18,255        
w2:                        
    ldi r19,255            
w1:                         
    dec r19               
    brne w1                 

    dec r18                 
    brne w2                 

    dec r17                 
    brne w3                 

    ret
```

Comment: You should tag this as assembly not c

Comment: Probably the most simple PRNG is some sort of *xorshift* algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift . Note that when writing the algorithm in assembler, you can take advantage of the fact that shift operations normally shift into the carry bit, something that cannot be done in C

Comment: Well sorry I wasn't actually sure which language this is cuz i started learning this last week in school. I meant the code to generate a random number in AVR Studio 4

Answer (score 3):

You can implement a version of the [xorshift suited to generate 8 bit](http://www.arklyffe.com/main/2010/08/29/xorshift-pseudorandom-number-generator/) pseudo-random numbers:

```
static uint8_t y8 = 1;

uint8_t xorshift8(void) {
    y8 ^= (y8 << 7);
    y8 ^= (y8 >> 5);
    return y8 ^= (y8 << 3);
}
```

I feel the urge to stress that this is **not** a [CSRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator).

In AVR assembly for ATMega168 we have:

```
;Return random number in r0
;The symbol xorshift_Y8 must be defined (it must be a SRAM address, i.e. > 0x60)
xorshift8:
  push r1
  push r2

  ldi r0, 128                ;r0 = 2^7
  lds r2, xorshift_Y8        ;r2 = y8
  mul r0, r2                 ;r1:r0 = y8 << 7
  eor r2, r0                 ;r2 = y8 ^ (y8 << 7)

  ;r2 = y8

  mov r0, r2                 ;r0 = y8
  andi r0, 0xf0              ;r0 = y8 high nibble
  swap r0                    ;r0 = y8 >> 4
  lsr r0                     ;r0 = y8 >> 5
  eor r2, r0                 ;r2 = y8 ^ (y8 >> 5)

  ;r2 = y8

  ldi r0, 8                  ;r0 = 2^3
  mul r2, r0                 ;r1:r0 = y8 << 3
  eor r0, r2                 ;r0 = y8 ^ (y8 << 3)

  sts xorshift_Y8, r0        ;Save new state

  pop r2
  pop r1
  ret
```

**Note** I haven't tested this code, use it as a template.
**Note 2** AVR has single bit shift, multiplication is fast enough to prefer it over multiple shift when it comes to code like `y8 << 7`.
**Note 3** Since there is no division and 2^32 has no modular inverse in the 8 bit realm, `y8 >> 5` is implemented by swapping *y8* nibbles, shifting one more bit right and masking out the useless bits. Not in this order.

---

The only thing left to do is initializing the `xorshift_Y8` variable, that is *seed* the RNG.
Enumerating all the sources of entropy in the ATMega168 is a too broad topic, you can start from the first [Google result](http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/how-do-you-seed-srand) for "avr random seed".
The main idea are:

- Start with a predefined value (like 1) and increment it at each startup.
- Use floating GPIO without pullups.
- Use a floating ADC input.
- Set a timer at startup, read the timer value at the first use (only) of the RNG.

The important thing is to **never** set the state to 0 since it is a "stable" state for xorshift!